# Delphi IOS Iphone TWebbrowser (Wkwebview) setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(true) does not work

Tags: ios, delphi, youtube, twebbrowser

I try to inbound a fmx.TWebbrowser (Delphi 11) for displaying an youtube stream in an iphone app.
If I click the stream picture, the stream opens in the iphone movieplayer-window. So I have to zoom out, to view the video in the app. On Android devices it works fine. Also, when I write the app in Xcode, I can set "plays inline" and the stream works inline at the wkwebview.

In Delphi / RAD, I can modify the FMX.Webbrowser.Cocoa. It is possible to use the function configuration.setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(true). If I check this afterwards, configuration.allowsinlineMediaPlayback remains false.

Example:

```
constructor TCommonWebBrowserService.Create; 
var test:Boolean;
begin
 FWebView := TNativeWebViewHelper.CreateAndInitWebView;
 FWebView.configuration.setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(True);
 test:=FWebView.configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback;
```

test remains False.

Apple writes: setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback must be set at creation.

At FMX.Webbrowser.Delegate.IOS there is

```
class function TNativeWebViewHelper.CreateAndInitWebView: WKWebView;
begin
 Result := TWKWebView.Create();
end;
```

but there is no way to set .configuration.setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(True);

At FMX.Webbrowser.delegate.ios there is a function called

```
function TWebViewDelegate.webViewCreateWebViewWithConfigura tion(webView: WKWebView; configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration;navigationAction: WKNavigationAction; windowFeatures: WKWindowFeatures): WKWebView;
```

but Delphi does not use this function.

Is there an override or a solution to this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can copy FMX.WebBrowser.Delegate.iOS.pas to project folder and modify TNativeWebViewHelper.CreateAndInitWebView to set config:

```
TNativeWebViewHelper.CreateAndInitWebView to set config:

class function TNativeWebViewHelper.CreateAndInitWebView: WKWebView;
var
  configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration;
begin
  configuration := TWKWebViewConfiguration.Create;
  configuration.setAllowsInlineMediaPlayback(True);
  configuration.setmediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback(0);

  Result := TWKWebView.Wrap(TWKWebView.Alloc.initWithFrame(
    CGRectFromRect(TRectF.Create(0, 0, 0, 0)), configuration));
end;
```